# Regex filter for stings that accepts all letters from UTF-8 with the exception of all non-letter characters but with the exception of - (hyphens)

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8, regexp-replace

I would to regex filter for stings in javascript, namely a rule or a set of rules that accepts all letters from UTF-8 with the exception of all non-letter characters with the exception of - (hyphens)

For example it is ok to pass the filter:

```
abcd
ab-cd
müller
1248
ab99
straße
café
façade
São-Paulo
România
etc..
```

But not the non-letter characters like to ex.:

```
!"§$%&/()=?`>°^_<|#'@, etc
```

I tried several ways with regex but without success.
Can you help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match letters and numbers `[\p{L}\p{N}]+` with the unicode flag, and if the hyphen should not be at the start or end optionally repeat that part:

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:-[\p{L}\p{N}]+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tBWq1d/1)

```js
const regex = /^[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:-[\p{L}\p{N}]+)*$/gmu;
const str = `abcd
ab-cd
müller
1248
ab99
straße
café
façade
São-Paulo
România
etc..
!
"
§
\$
%
&
/
(
)
=
?
\`
>
°
^
_
<
|
#
'
@
,
`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: Thank you!, Is looking good. I will use your pattern with .replace(regex) in javascript and I see it does not work like in your example with .match(regex). Can you please adapt so that is work with replace() too.

Comment: @Java The current pattern matches the words on the whole line. What do you want to accomplish using replace? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Java Do you mean like the other way around? `[^\p{L}\p{N}-]+` https://regex101.com/r/4LNi6C/1

Comment: @ The fourth bird, Heel veel dank! Is work perfectly!
This are all rules I use: _word
      .replace(/\.eth$/, "") // to remove the string ".eth"
      .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, "") // one or more consecutive dashes at the beginn or end
      .replace(/\s/, "-") // replace a empty space with "-" (ex: São-Paulo become São-Paulo)
      .replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}-]+/gmu, "") // your engine
      .toLowerCase();

Comment: The only thing on my TODO is to accept emojis too. I found this regex and I ask you if you ca add this to your "engine" please :) https://www.regextester.com/106421

Comment: For emojis I add this  \p{So} and is work.  replace(/[^\p{L}\p{N}\p{So}-]+/gmu, "");

Comment: @Java Glad it works for you :-) On this page for example you can find more unicode categories https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html